# A Jquery rotator that doesn't suck?

Tags: jquery, rotator

I've been looking all over the place for a simple jquery rotator that has next/prev buttons, that will automatically fade through 5 or so images... so far everything is over complicated and not at all what I want or its so simple that it doesn't have any functionality other than switching between images...

so basically I'm asking if anyone knows of a Jquery image rotator that doesn't completely suck... lol

btw these are the things I would want it to do

1. rotate through images automatically
2. fade
3. have next and prev buttons

thanks

Answer (score 8):

Build your own.  It's a fairly simple script.
Something like this might get you started:

html:

```
<div class="rotator">
  <img src="img1.jpg" />
  <img src="img2.jpg" />
  <img src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
<a id="rotator-prev" href="#">Previous</a> 
<a id="rotator-next" href="#">Next</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allImgs = $('.rotator img');

    allImgs.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }).hide();

    var currIdx = 0;
    allImgs.first().show();

    function next() {
        var nextIdx = currIdx + 1;
        if (nextIdx >= allImgs.length) nextIdx = 0;
        allImgs.eq(currIdx).fadeOut();
        allImgs.eq(nextIdx).fadeIn();
        currIdx = nextIdx;
    }

    function prev() {
        var prevIdx = currIdx - 1;
        if (prevIdx < 0) prevIdx = allImgs.length - 1;
        allImgs.eq(currIdx).fadeOut();
        allImgs.eq(prevIdx).fadeIn();
        currIdx = prevIdx;
    }

    function doAuto() {
        next();
        setTimeout(doAuto, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(doAuto, 5000);

    $('#rotator-prev').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        prev();
    });
    $('#rotator-next').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        next();
    });
});
```

---

you can see this code with real images (and a few css tweaks) [running at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SXcNy/](http://jsfiddle.net/SXcNy/).

Comment: I used your idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598737/automated-fade-cycle-on-click-also Only that i need to slide one more div also :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy Slider, its easy and awesome!

http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

and demos here:

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html
http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html
http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/03.html

Answer (score 1):

Best one I had found to date is **Orbit** from the [Zurb](http://www.zurb.com/) crew. It recently got assimilated into their **[Foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/)**, but you can still **[download the standalone plugin here](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider)**

The code is VERY lightweight and aside from offering intuitive controls it has a nifty timer integrated with the play/pause button. By far the best choice in terms of a free solution.

If you are looking to pay for something with more whistles/bells and fancy pro transitions, you should check out **[WOW Slider](http://wowslider.com/)** or **[TN3 Gallery](http://www.tn3gallery.com/)**

Comment: I am using Orbit right now and I have found it to be inconsistent, and buggy on older IE browsers. So I am looking for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't plugins at jQuery website are enough for you. This has all you need http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/image-rotator

here are demos:  http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-pinboard-fly-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Try jCarousel

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I wanted a simple image/content slideshow plugin but could only find ones with loads of features and skins etc that I didn't need. So I made [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) - just so I had a simple plugin I could extend as I needed, rather than using a full featured one and removing features that I didn't need. If you decide to give it a try and have any problems, please let me know and I'll do what I can to help.